# $ABCD$ : square and $E\in BD$ prove that $CE⊥PQ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Problem :

Let the square $ABCD$ and $E$ point in $BD$

and $P_{AD}(E)=J$ , $P_{AB}(E)=H$ ($P$ : projection orthogonal of E  ...)

Now we need prove that $CE\perp JH$  ( perpendicular ) for any point $E$ in $BD$
My idea take a $(D,DC,DA)$

Then I will search cordone of point $E,C,H,J$

$D=(0,0),A=(0,a),C(a,0)$ but I don't how I find cordone of $E$
I need see other method if exist 
Can we use barycenter here ?

[image]

Comment: You need to prove it for **any** point $E$. The only thing about it you know is that it is on $BD$. So the coordinates of $E$ are $(x,x)$, with $0\lt x\lt 1$.

Comment: yes sir @Andei , thanks

Comment: For simplicity, if you're using an analytic approach, take $$A(0,1)\quad B(1,1)\quad C(1,0)\quad D(0,0)$$ Observe now that $E$ lies on the line defined by $y=x$ and therefore $E$ has the coordinates $(e,e)$ for some $e\in(0,1)$.

Comment: However, I would use a purely geometrical approach...

Comment: @Dr.Mathva , $E\in BD$ not  in medal

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The red segments are diagonals of congruent rectangles, which can be overlapped through a $90^\circ$ rotation around their common vertex, followed by a translation. It follows that the red segments are orthogonal.

Comment: Very nice done , thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I would rather use a purely geometrical approach:

[image]

> **Hint:** Show that the green and blue triangles are similar.

It's easy to take it from here since $JE\parallel DC\implies \angle IEJ=\angle ECD\implies...$

---

*For the analytical approach:* Take $E(e,e)$ considering that $0\leqslant e\leqslant 1$. Therefore $H(e, 1)$ and $J(0, e)$. Now, it is just a matter of evaluating slopes. Observe that $$m_{HJ}=\frac{1-e}{e}\qquad m_{CE}=-\frac{e}{1-e}\qquad \implies \qquad m_{HJ}\cdot m_{EC}=-1$$

Comment: Beautiful solution @Dr.Mathva

Answer (score 1):

I like analytical approach better: $J$ is at $(0,x)$, $H$ is at $(x,a)$. The slope of $CE$ is $$m_{CE}=\frac{0-x}{a-x}$$The slope of $JH$ is $$m_{JH}=\frac{a-x}{x-0}$$
Multiply the two and you get $$m_{CE}\cdot m_{JH}=-1$$
So they are perpendicular

Comment: Nice! @Andrei , thanks!